# Has any culture in history ever not invented digits, and just used letters?

Tags: numbers, linguistics

We have characters for letters and numbers. We typically view them as a discrete sets. Has any culture ever mangled the two? To some degree it seems almost logical if your letters are already conceptually ordinal,

- *I have a pear.* becomes *I have 1 pear*
- *I have b pear.* becomes *I have 2 pears*

Comment: See [Alphabetic numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetic_numeral_system):"Alphabetic numeral systems originated with Greek numerals around 600 BC and became largely extinct by the 16th century". [Greek](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals) and [Hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_numerals) alphabetic numerals are still in use for some ordinals, mathematicians use some Hebrew numerals for infinite cardinalities (aleph, beth).

Comment: @Conifold to your last point there: there's also  $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to represent infinitesimals in calculus.

Comment: Roman numerals I, V, X, L, C, M, D are also letters. Perhaps this is a common way of development: first use letters and only later invent special digits for numbers.

Comment: "digits" are symbols. Many symbols have been used in history to name numbers. See [Numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system) and Karl Menninger, ][Number Words and Number Symbols:](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Number_Words_and_Number_Symbols/RXbCAgAAQBAJ)

Comment: In Hebrew alphabet every letter has numerical value, http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/hebrew-numbers.html